# BigByteList with a managed wrapper

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am a novice when it comes to C++ (as well as C++/CLI). I am trying to write a minimal 64-bit implementation of a List in C++ (using `unsigned __int64` as the index data type), to store `unsigned char` values (bytes), as well as a C++/CLI wrapper for it that I will use to later to talk to it in C# land.

I may have succeeded (preliminary tests look good), so I am submitting the code for your review. Any helpful comments about changes I could make the code better would be appreciated, as well as comments about where the code might break down (this will be my first unmanaged / managed code wrapper).

Some background: I wrote this code because I needed a larger byte list in C#. I am working on a 64-bit memory scanner, and want to eventually suspend a program, then copy it in its entirety into a giant byte list for later digestion.

```
//UnmanagedBigByteList.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class UnmanagedBigByteList
{
private:
    std::uint64_t _capacity = 4;
    std::uint64_t _count = 0;
    std::uint8_t* _items;

    void grow()
    {
        std::uint64_t newcapacity = _capacity * 2;
        std::uint8_t* newitems = new std::uint8_t[newcapacity];
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < _capacity; i++)
        {
            newitems[i] = _items[i];
            //std::cout << "Adding " << i << " Element to grown list." << std::endl;
        }
        delete[] _items;
        _items = newitems;
        _capacity = newcapacity;
    }

public:
    UnmanagedBigByteList()
    {
        _items = new std::uint8_t[_capacity];
    }


    ~UnmanagedBigByteList()
    {
        delete[] _items;
    }

    void Add(std::uint8_t byte)
    {
        if (_capacity == _count)
        {
            grow();
        }
        _items[_count] = byte;
        _count++;

    }

    void Clear() 
    {
        delete[] _items;
        _capacity = 4;
        _count = 0;
        _items = new std::uint8_t[_capacity];
    
    }

    bool Contains(std::uint8_t byte)
    {
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < _count; i++)
        {
            if (byte == _items[i]) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
       
    }

    bool IndexOf(std::uint8_t byte, std::uint64_t* index)
    {
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < _count; i++)
        {
            if (byte == _items[i])
            {
                *(index) = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    
    
    }

    std::uint64_t Count()
    {
        return _count;
    }

    std::uint64_t Capacity()
    {
        return _capacity;
    }

    std::uint8_t& operator[](std::uint64_t index)
    {
        return _items[index];
    }
};

//ManagedBigByteList.h
#pragma once
#include "UnmanagedBigByteList.h"

using namespace System;

namespace BigGenerics {
    public ref class ManagedBigByteList
    {
    private:
        UnmanagedBigByteList* _ubbl;
    public:
        ManagedBigByteList()
        {
            _ubbl = new UnmanagedBigByteList();
        }
        ~ManagedBigByteList()
        {
            delete _ubbl;
        }

        void Add(std::uint8_t byte)
        {
            _ubbl->Add(byte);
        }

        void Clear() 
        {
            _ubbl->Clear(); 
        }

        bool Contains(std::uint8_t byte)
        {
            return _ubbl->Contains(byte);       
        }

        bool IndexOf(std::uint8_t byte, std::uint64_t* index)
        {
            return _ubbl->IndexOf(byte, index);
        }

        property std::uint64_t Count
        {
            std::uint64_t get()
            {
                return _ubbl->Count();
            }
        }

        property std::uint64_t Capacity
        {
            std::uint64_t get()
            {
                return _ubbl->Capacity();
            }
        }

        property std::uint8_t& default[std::uint64_t]
        {
            std::uint8_t& get(std::uint64_t index)
            {
                return (*(_ubbl))[index];
            }
            void set(std::uint64_t index, std::uint8_t& value)
            {
                (*(_ubbl))[index] = value;
            }
        }

    };
}


//BigGenericsTest.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "ManagedBigByteList.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace BigGenerics;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    ManagedBigByteList^ newList = gcnew ManagedBigByteList();

    for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        std::uint8_t newItem = i;
        
        newList->Add(newItem);
    }

    //unsigned char newItem2 = 200;
    //newList[59] = newItem2;

    //unsigned char* newItem3 = new unsigned char(150);
    //newList[58] = *newItem3;
    //newList[59] = unsigned char(2000);
    System::Console::WriteLine("Checking if IndexOf() works.");
    std::uint64_t* index;
    if (newList->IndexOf(std::uint8_t(30), index))
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("IndexOf works!");
        System::Console::WriteLine("Value of 30 found at: " + *index);
    }
    
    for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < newList->Count; i++)
    {

        System::Console::WriteLine(i + " Element is: " + newList[i].ToString());
        //unsigned char newItem = i;
        //newList->Add(newItem);
    }
    
    //System::Console::WriteLine("First Element is: " + newList[0].ToString());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently there is. :-). I've updated the code. I've been using this (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/managed-types-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160) as a guide to the data types (C++ vs. .Net), which is why I was using the double-underscore type. Is there a better guide, or is it just something you become familiar with as you learn the language?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid - I only use standard C++, and very averse to using compilers' internal types.  That's why I asked.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` to store the bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't simply use a `List<byte>` in C# or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` in C++ as already mentioned by G.Sliepen.

I'm going to ignore that for now and continue with the review.

## Use the correct types.

You should use `std::size_t` instead of `std::uint64_t` for the array size and index variables. Using `std::uint64_t` in 32-bit mode will not allow your list to be any bigger than using a 32-bit type.

## Shrinking the list

Consider adding a `ShrinkToSize` function. Your current implementation only allows for the list to grow.

## Checking if `new` was successful

You cannot simply assume that there is enough memory available.

## Optimizing `Grow`

In `void grow()` you copy the existing element one by one. Modern compilers may be smart enough to automatically translate this into a call to `memcpy` or `memmove` but I would rather have used `std::copy`.

For these types of lists with **basic** types, good old C's memory allocation functions have an ace up its sleeve over C++'s `new` and `delete`. You could have used `malloc` instead of `new` and `free` instead of `delete` and then `realloc` to grow or shrink the list.

## Using templates

You can use templates to make your list reusable for different types:

```
template <class T>
class UnmanagedBigByteList
{
private:
    std::uint64_t _capacity = 4;
    std::uint64_t _count = 0;
    T* _items;
    // ...
}
```

```
template <class T>
public ref class ManagedBigByteList
{
private:
    UnmanagedBigByteList<T>* _ubbl;
public:
    ManagedBigByteList()
    {
        _ubbl = new UnmanagedBigByteList<T>();
    }
    // ...
}
```

```
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    ManagedBigByteList<std::uint8_t>^ newList = gcnew ManagedBigByteList<std::uint8_t>();
    for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        std::uint8_t newItem = i;
        newList->Add(newItem);
    }
    // ..
}
```

## Final thoughts

I suspect that you may be trying to implement a 64-bit List in a 32-bit address space. This is not impossible but would be much more complicated than simply using 64-bit size and index variables.

To do this you will need to split the list into blocks/pages that can either be in RAM or in a file. How to manage this optimally would make a great new question :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your review. 
What I've been trying to do is implement a 64-bit memory scanner in C# (in which I copy the entirety of a live, but suspended program, into a giant byte list for analysis), but ran into the problem that the largest number of elements someone can allocate (for a list) in .Net is a uint32's max value. To get around this, I am writing part of it in unmanaged C++, with a managed C++ wrapper. The machine I am developing this on is a Threadripper, with 256 GB of RAM, so there is plenty of memory for scanning and debugging 64-bit programs.

Comment: Does std::vector support an unsigned int64's max value worth of elements?

I tried writing this initially with templates in mind, but incompatibilities between generics and templates had me giving up in frustration. 

Everything else is spot on. I thank you for your time, and patience. I wish I could reward you more.

Comment: @user3799003, `std::vector` does not have this same stupid limitation as `List` so you are good to go!

Comment: @user3799003, one more thing that you should consider is that there is a cost involved every time you move between the managed and unmanaged space. It may be better to batch your calls to `BigByteList` instead of adding one element at a time. Here it would be best to experiment and see what is the most efficient =)